# Mail user information every day with contents from a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, email, newsletter

I am creating a site which you can post reminders.

I have tried much, but can't seem to be able to send a user an email every day with their reminders in.

I can get the content, through php, but don't know how to automatically send a message every day.

How can I do this through php or any other method?

My database looks like:

```
Users Table
->User's Row
------->email
------->other fields

Content Table
->User's Post row
------->Content
------->Other
```

I doubt that the database structure is important, but it is there if you need it.

**Just to Clarify:** Send each user a seperate email with their content.

Thanks

Update:  I have seen a lot of people talking about cron jobs and perl, but I don't have that sort of support for my hosting :(. Are there any other solutions, or a way to find a seperate *perl only* hosting with just the cron job in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something has to tell your PHP script to execute. Look at [cron](http://unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html) which does just that!

Say your script is called `daily-email.php`. A simple crontab setup to run this script daily at 4am would be:

```
00 04 * * * /path/to/php /path/to/daily-email.php
```

Answer (score 2):

Read about cron jobs (Linux) or scheduled tasks (Windows).

Answer (score 1):

to do that, you'll need to use cron jobs, see if your webhost supports them. You can use cron jobs to run php scripts on regular intervals.

Answer (score 0):

check here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron
write a script(myfile.php) that u want to be executed everyday, thn execute this cron expression
 0 0 * * * /myfile.php